# Symbolicating report and understanding what I need to fix. App rejected due to crash on launch

Tags: xcode, symbolicatecrash

Can I please get some guidance on how to identify why the app crashes on launch according to apple? I ran my react-native app using 'npx expo start' in VScode with no problem. The .xcworkspace in XCode launches with no problem. My submission was rejected due to crash on launch:

Apple provided crashlog.txt files and suggests the following: " To address the crash in your app, follow these steps:

I previously ran a few terminal commands to symbolicate the crash report. I got an output file but I don't know how to read it or figure out what it is telling me to fix.

Crashlog.txt is below:

```
{"app_name":"xp1","timestamp":"2023-11-12 09:40:40.00 +0100","app_version":"2.2.6","slice_uuid":"62eee64f-21a9-32b4-9c23-d9652b7a76c1","adam_id":"6470176329","build_version":"2.2.6","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.xp1.ios","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 17.1 (21B74)","roots_installed":0,"name":"xp1","incident_id":"34BD7151-519A-4F8E-AD9B-8BB922FF3C96"}
{
  "uptime" : 420000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad11,6",
  "coalitionID" : 3117,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 17.1",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "21B74"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-11-12 09:40:40.4717 +0100",
  "codeSigningMonitor" : 1,
  "incident" : "34BD7151-519A-4F8E-AD9B-8BB922FF3C96",
  "pid" : 7104,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-11-12 09:40:39.8577 +0100",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 10287457915461,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 10287472490326,
  "procName" : "xp1",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/50CCA906-9002-4080-A02E-15F310D675F5\/xp1.app\/xp1",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"2.2.6","CFBundleVersion":"2.2.6","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.xp1.ios","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"15A240a"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6470176329","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"833A1E3D-B027-4923-8FA8-41FFAA4E4261","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"860882731"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.xp1.ios",
  "crashReporterKey" : "ed02189e7e1b64496910a0eba79e90537f843919",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.xp1.ios",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "C87NL9M4LL",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 7,
  "instructionByteStream" : {"beforePC":"fyMD1f17v6n9AwCR893\/l78DAJH9e8Go\/w9f1sADX9YQKYDSARAA1A==","atPC":"AwEAVH8jA9X9e7+p\/QMAkejd\/5e\/AwCR\/XvBqP8PX9bAA1\/WfyMD1Q=="},
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap: 6","byProc":"xp1","byPid":7104},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":968816,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":179200,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1083016,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1534544,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1536644,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":203140,"symbol":"__invoking___","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":201756,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invoke]","symbolLocation":428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":201284,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":1277088,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1285360,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1284416,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":9896,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":17152,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":47252,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":748,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":50116,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":380,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":94212,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":92280,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":404,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":6500,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6660,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}],
  "faultingThread" : 3,
  "threads" : [{"id":2013831,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":8157814176,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$_UIKeyboardExtensionInputMode"},{"value":288230384296830717,"symbolLocation":288230376151711749,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$_UIKeyboardInputModeController"},{"value":8145118968,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$_UIKeyboardInputModeController"},{"value":4664454656},{"value":13},{"value":4664454656},{"value":1536},{"value":1776},{"value":8130203648},{"value":18323354445983907968},{"value":2606670966425484},{"value":35747326706454016},{"value":72},{"value":4664201824},{"value":72057602182612217,"symbolLocation":72057594037927937,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$___NSCFString"},{"value":8144684280,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$___NSCFString"},{"value":6656099684,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"objc_alloc"},{"value":6},{"value":0},{"value":10749318544},{"value":10798636064},{"value":0},{"value":8145170432,"symbolLocation":56,"symbol":"_MergedGlobals.38"},{"value":1},{"value":1336},{"value":0},{"value":352},{"value":0},{"value":4663144128}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":6822763048},"cpsr":{"value":1610612736},"fp":{"value":6089741424},"sp":{"value":6089741392},"esr":{"value":2449473543,"description":"(Data Abort) byte read Translation fault"},"pc":{"value":6656099688},"far":{"value":8157814176}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":247144,"symbol":"objc_alloc","symbolLocation":4,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1317416,"symbol":"+[UIKeyboardInputMode keyboardInputModeWithIdentifier:]","symbolLocation":220,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1313396,"symbol":"-[UIKeyboardInputModeController currentInputModeInPreference]","symbolLocation":412,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1312596,"symbol":"-[UIKeyboardInputModeController currentInputMode]","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1312240,"symbol":"-[UIInputWindowController updateSupportsDockViewController]","symbolLocation":144,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1312080,"symbol":"-[UIInputWindowController _updateContentOverlayInsetsForSelfAndChildren]","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1307664,"symbol":"-[UIViewController _updateLayoutForStatusBarAndInterfaceOrientation]","symbolLocation":424,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1305512,"symbol":"-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":70484,"symbol":"-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]","symbolLocation":1128,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":68640,"symbol":"__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":68404,"symbol":"-[UIView _postMovedFromSuperview:]","symbolLocation":484,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":63376,"symbol":"-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]","symbolLocation":2200,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":17551060,"symbol":"-[UITextEffectsWindow addSubview:]","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":552800,"symbol":"-[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible]","symbolLocation":728,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1638188,"symbol":"-[UIWindow setRootViewController:]","symbolLocation":364,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1637548,"symbol":"-[UITextEffectsWindow _commonInitWithOptions:]","symbolLocation":252,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1637260,"symbol":"-[UITextEffectsWindow(UIObjectsForPerCanvas) _initWithCanvas:options:]","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1050740,"symbol":"+[_UIObjectPerCanvas objectOfClass:forCanvas:withOptions:createIfNecessary:]","symbolLocation":660,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1049920,"symbol":"+[UITextEffectsWindow _sharedTextEffectsWindowforWindowScene:allowHosted:forViewService:matchesStatusBarOrientationOnAccess:shouldCreateIfNecessary:]","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1049256,"symbol":"+[UITextEffectsWindow sharedTextEffectsWindowForWindowScene:forViewService:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":1048864,"symbol":"-[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate containerWindowForViewService:]","symbolLocation":332,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":2749076,"symbol":"__82-[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _scene:willTransitionToActivationState:withReasonsMask:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":68,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":9896,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":17152,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":76184,"symbol":"_dispatch_main_queue_drain","symbolLocation":984,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":75184,"symbol":"_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":225804,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":212760,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1996,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":210536,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":13804,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2278036,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":888,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":2275536,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":25576,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":24012,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2240,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":2013882,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":10}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6090305536},{"value":5383},{"value":6089768960},{"value":0},{"value":409603},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6090305536},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8557681148},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2013883,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":10}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6090878976},{"value":4867},{"value":6090342400},{"value":6090877824},{"value":5193731},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6090877808},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8557681148},"far":{"value":0}}},{"triggered":true,"id":2013884,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":8556847983},{"value":6091450384},{"value":110},{"value":0},{"value":6593053409038274171},{"value":6593053412646174331},{"value":512},{"value":6091449152},{"value":0},{"value":2095104},{"value":16},{"value":0},{"value":328},{"value":6091452416},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":8707},{"value":6091452640},{"value":276},{"value":6091452640},{"value":10782755688},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":10754446784},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8557696640},"cpsr":{"value":1073741824},"fp":{"value":6091450240},"sp":{"value":6091450208},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7982157852,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":0}},"queue":"com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue","frames":[{"imageOffset":40988,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":22144,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":482192,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":71264,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":5676,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":348,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":191796,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":144,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":68132,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":68040,"symbol":"std::terminate()","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":17172,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":47252,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":748,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":50116,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":380,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":94212,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":92280,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":404,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":6500,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6660,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":2013885,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":18951},{"value":3},{"value":16},{"value":6091990048},{"value":6092022816},{"value":132097},{"value":0},{"value":3},{"value":45},{"value":9219},{"value":1},{"value":68719476736},{"value":1140912128},{"value":0},{"value":478},{"value":6092025856},{"value":0},{"value":2147484415},{"value":3},{"value":6092026080},{"value":4},{"value":6092026080},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":10754445568},{"value":4664152120},{"value":308}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8557682256},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":6092024064},"sp":{"value":6092024032},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7982124164},"far":{"value":0}},"queue":"com.apple.runningboardservices.background-workloop","frames":[{"imageOffset":7300,"symbol":"__bsdthread_ctl","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":7760,"symbol":"_pthread_set_properties_self","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":26944,"symbol":"_dispatch_set_priority_and_mach_voucher_slow","symbolLocation":204,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":27396,"symbol":"_dispatch_set_priority_and_voucher_slow","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":55268,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_invoke","symbolLocation":2072,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":94212,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":92280,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":404,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":6500,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6660,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":2013886,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","threadState":{"x":[{"value":268451845},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":9580,"symbol":"MIL::Operators::Common::ios17::Resample::Make(MIL::MILContext&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>)"},{"value":65983582568448},{"value":0},{"value":65983582568448},{"value":2},{"value":4294967295},{"value":18446744073709550527},{"value":15363},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":15363},{"value":772630},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":18446744073709551569},{"value":6919885028,"symbolLocation":56,"symbol":"clock_gettime"},{"value":0},{"value":4294967295},{"value":2},{"value":65983582568448},{"value":0},{"value":65983582568448},{"value":6092594552},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":9580,"symbol":"MIL::Operators::Common::ios17::Resample::Make(MIL::MILContext&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>)"},{"value":21592279046},{"value":21592279046},{"value":4412409862}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":7982120816},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":6092594400},"sp":{"value":6092594320},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7982121432},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":4568,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3952,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3720,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3272,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":220428,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":211972,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":210536,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":181580,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":369276,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":1630120,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":420,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":725380,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":732,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":9428,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6672,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":2013887,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":10}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6093172736},{"value":16643},{"value":6092636160},{"value":0},{"value":409603},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6093172736},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8557681148},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2013888,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":10}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6093746176},{"value":0},{"value":6093209600},{"value":0},{"value":278532},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6093746176},"esr":{"value":0,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8557681148},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2013889,"name":"com.facebook.react.JavaScript","threadState":{"x":[{"value":268451845},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":9580,"symbol":"MIL::Operators::Common::ios17::Resample::Make(MIL::MILContext&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>)"},{"value":95670396518400},{"value":0},{"value":95670396518400},{"value":2},{"value":4294967295},{"value":18446744073709550527},{"value":22275},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":22275},{"value":945398},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":18446744073709551569},{"value":6919885028,"symbolLocation":56,"symbol":"clock_gettime"},{"value":0},{"value":4294967295},{"value":2},{"value":95670396518400},{"value":0},{"value":95670396518400},{"value":6094314936},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":9580,"symbol":"MIL::Operators::Common::ios17::Resample::Make(MIL::MILContext&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>)"},{"value":21592279046},{"value":21592279046},{"value":4412409862}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":7982120816},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":6094314784},"sp":{"value":6094314704},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7982121432},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":4568,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3952,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3720,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3272,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":220428,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":211972,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":210536,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":1157740,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":725380,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":732,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":9428,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6672,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":2013890,"name":"hades","threadState":{"x":[{"value":260},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":160},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6094892728},{"value":0},{"value":10790258952},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":305},{"value":8299326672},{"value":0},{"value":10790258928},{"value":10790258992},{"value":6094893280},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":256},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8557678548},"cpsr":{"value":1610612736},"fp":{"value":6094892848},"sp":{"value":6094892704},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7982123900},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":7036,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4052,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1228,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":77516,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":1164280,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1163692,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":9428,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6672,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":2013891,"name":"hermes-chrome-inspector-conn","threadState":{"x":[{"value":260},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":160},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6095465992},{"value":0},{"value":10788147168},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":305},{"value":8299326672},{"value":0},{"value":10788147144},{"value":10788147256},{"value":6095466720},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":256},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8557678548},"cpsr":{"value":1610612736},"fp":{"value":6095466112},"sp":{"value":6095465968},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7982123900},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":7036,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4052,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1228,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":77516,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":2261764,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1972764,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":9428,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6672,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":2013892,"name":"hermes-inspector","threadState":{"x":[{"value":260},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":160},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6096039432},{"value":0},{"value":10788147360},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":305},{"value":8299326672},{"value":0},{"value":10788147336},{"value":10788147448},{"value":6096040160},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":256},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8557678548},"cpsr":{"value":1610612736},"fp":{"value":6096039552},"sp":{"value":6096039408},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7982123900},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":7036,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4052,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1228,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":77516,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":2261764,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1972764,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":9428,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":6672,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":10}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4383571968,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "004cd10c-9ab5-3df6-b6af-a18ad3e128c8",
    "path" : "\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/libobjc-trampolines.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc-trampolines.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4393631744,
    "size" : 3063808,
    "uuid" : "473b6e74-73cb-3f91-943d-f00d8785d17e",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/50CCA906-9002-4080-A02E-15F310D675F5\/xp1.app\/Frameworks\/hermes.framework\/hermes",
    "name" : "hermes"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4377133056,
    "size" : 3768320,
    "uuid" : "62eee64f-21a9-32b4-9c23-d9652b7a76c1",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/50CCA906-9002-4080-A02E-15F310D675F5\/xp1.app\/xp1",
    "name" : "xp1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6655852544,
    "size" : 319233,
    "uuid" : "4af3b26f-95f5-3a0c-be43-ddd978e6bc2f",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libobjc.A.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6821445632,
    "size" : 28098560,
    "uuid" : "21555085-b1bb-327d-b244-471f789327c4",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6919573504,
    "size" : 290816,
    "uuid" : "89420547-98a3-352a-ad2b-bbcb6006fb29",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6785646592,
    "size" : 5427200,
    "uuid" : "b37a1273-b0c2-312e-9e0b-7143fb645c69",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7913893888,
    "size" : 36864,
    "uuid" : "4be6d9c6-8725-3c03-b3f9-b9a7a5b1ec06",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
    "name" : "GraphicsServices"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7367086080,
    "size" : 555740,
    "uuid" : "a795ad37-6266-385e-95e6-c1ca804c926e",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8557674496,
    "size" : 49140,
    "uuid" : "810e428a-f26d-37bb-bb0f-609cbb4718c7",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7982116864,
    "size" : 233472,
    "uuid" : "77ac893d-8258-332b-9dfc-b7ba2439af97",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6919864320,
    "size" : 516084,
    "uuid" : "bdb2e656-dfd8-3f53-8384-d686e76fedcb",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8556761088,
    "size" : 98304,
    "uuid" : "36326474-e3b5-3240-8985-f554caa59001",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++abi.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++abi.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6768476160,
    "size" : 11952128,
    "uuid" : "8ddf9bda-f5fb-3020-9be1-05bc15fcfba1",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8586637312,
    "size" : 5173244,
    "uuid" : "66f21a5c-9a38-3855-80d6-ea84d7ef9ed9",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/MIL.framework\/MIL",
    "name" : "MIL"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7055724544,
    "size" : 581632,
    "uuid" : "b88d4907-d976-335d-a8b9-db16463e7238",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++.1.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++.1.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6654935040,
  "size" : 3482353664,
  "uuid" : "0491620d-8ecc-32bb-b5e2-e9596bfa44ba"
},
```

Comment: Rename the crash file with an extension of ips and then open it in Xcode. Xcode will prompt you for the associated project and then it will symbolicate the crash log and show you where it crashed within your own code.

Comment: Thanks for that. I renamed the file, .ipa and .ips just in case but neither one prompted for the associated project. Any way I can trigger the prompt for associated prompt manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this command in VSCode 'npx expo start --no-dev --minify' which gave me a production build of my project. I was then able to identify the cause of the crash through the simulator console without needing to symbolicate the crashlog.txt.

This command is very useful for identifying cause of crashes in production.